# Custom Repository using Entity Manager in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I observed that the `.save()` method executes an extra `SELECT` query to check whether the corresponding record already exists when the corresponding ID is not a `AUTO INCREMENT` one.

I tried to implement a repository for this kind of situation that will be extended **by many** `JpaRepository` interfaces which will be used across different stateless services and I would like to know if my code is safe - race conditions wise - accross multiple requests as I am not that comfortable using the `EntityManager` yet.

User Entity :

```
public class User  {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 256)
    private String password;
}
```

**Solution 1** :

```
public interface SimpleRepository<T> {

    void persist(T entity);
}

public class SimpleRepositoryImpl<T> implements SimpleRepository<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void persist(T entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }
}
```

User Repository :

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>, SimpleRepository<User> {}
```

User Service :

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
  

    public void createUser(User user) {
        this.userRepository.persist(user);
    }
}
```

The same implementation will be followed across many different JPA Repositories and Services in the application.

If the solution above **is not safe** how about this one?

```
@Service
public class PersistenceService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public <T> void persist(T entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }

}
```

Which will turn my UserService and every other Service that is in need of the same functionality to :

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserService {

    private final PersistenceService persistenceService;
  
    public void createUser(User user) {
        this.persistenceService.persist(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating this won't solve a thing. It isn't the save method that executes the additional select it is JPA. So trying to shoehorn a new method inthere won't change a thing it will only introduce complexity.

Comment: @M.Deinum I was refering to the save method of JpaRepository which corressponds to the save method of CrudRepository. I don't understand why this won't solve a thing but I see how complexity is being introduced. Both of the solutions do not trigger a SELECT before INSERT but complexity aside, is this a safe approach accross multiple requests?

Comment: Eventually the `save` method calls `entitymanager.persist` or `entitymanager.merge` as well. So it has nothing to do with Spring Data JPA but how JPA works, the same will happen if you use `entitymanager.merge` yourself.